# MySQL query to find managers who are also employees (not managers) in (an)other department(s)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm given this schema:

```
Emp(eid: integer,ename: string,age: integer,salary: real)
Works(eid:integer,did: integer,pct_time: integer)
Dept(did:integer,budget: real,managerid:integer)
```

I'm having trouble conceptualizing what needs to be done. I'm thinking of getting a listing of all the managerid's and then somehow using IN with a subquery against eid's but I am not getting how it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Works.eid 
from Works inner join Dept using (did)
where Works.eid != Dept.managerid 
  and Works.eid in (select managerid as eid from Dept)
```

Answer (score 0):

We miss one information: is there a Works row for the manager? I assumed there was.

```
Select d1.managerid
From Dept as d1
Where Exists 
(Select 1 from Works 
 Join Dept as d2 using (did)
 Where Works.eid = d1.managerid 
 And Works.eid != d2.managerid)
```

I think it is better to use "exists" than "in".

If you need complete information for the returned manager, you need to add a join Emp in the main query.